# Can I read XML Attributes dynamically in WPF C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Hi I have one big concern about reading XML attributes like

```
<xmlNode attribute1="somevalue1" attribute2="somevalue2" attribute3="somevalue3">
```

Can we read attribiute1, attribute2 or attribute3 dynamically? I know we can read attribute values by `nd.Attributes["attribiute1"].Value`. but how to read this "attribute1" dynamically?

Comment: Something like `foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in nd.Attributes)`?

Comment: Did you try `Attributes[index]`?

Comment: who do you mean by `dynamically`..?

Comment: @Adriano what makes that dynamic?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "Dynamic" so we can try to help.

Comment: @Anirudha I _supposed_ he means "where number of attributes is unknown and not hard-coded". That's the reason of question mark...

Comment: foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in nd.Attributes) works fine for me.. Thanks Adriano. Sorry I am new in C# and saw many xaml solutions not the code solution. And thats why I have written dynamically. Sorry if misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(@"your xml");
foreach (var attr in xml.Attributes())
{

}
```

This is not specific to WPF, it works wherever you have access to the linq to xml provider